# What happens to the constants of the integral of x cos x dx?

Tags: integration

Really simple question regarding integration by parts. I don't see why the integral of $x \cos(x) dx$ is what it is. Here's what I do, what am I doing wrong? I proceed by integration by parts, setting $f(x) = x$ and $g'(x) = \cos(x)$. So we have that $f'(x) = 1$ and $g(x) = \sin(x) + C$.

$\int x \cos(x) \ dx = x(\sin(x) + C_1) - \int\sin(x) + C_2 \ dx$.

Different constants since they are not necessarily the same, right?

$= x\sin(x) + xC_1 + \cos(x) - C_3 - xC_2$
$= x\sin(x) + \cos(x) + x(C_1 - C_2) + C_3$.

However, the solution shouldn't actually include that third term, so what's the deal?

Comment: The constants should be the same... (and thus cancel)

Comment: The comment by @AndrewLi is right. The formula for integration by parts refers to a single function $g$, not two functions that differ by a constant. In your example, $g(x)$ can be $\sin(x)+C$ for any constant you like, but it has to be the same constant throughout the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you take the (indefinite) integral you add a constant. When you derivate you **do not** add a constant:  $$ f(x)+c \to (d/dx) \to f'(x) +0 $$ and look to it in the reverse and you will get the point.

Now
$$ F(x) = f(x)g(x)+c\;\to\;F'(x)=(f(x)g(x)+c)'=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$$
but
$$ F(x) = (f(x)+b)g(x)+c\;\to\;F'(x)=((f(x)+b)g(x)+c)'=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)+bg'(x)$$
again, reverse the view going back and you'll get the point :i.e. the correct interpretation of indefinite summation by parts.